# Taking 2 dimensional array and outputting 1 dimensional array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to take a two-dimensional array and run it through a series of calculations in order to transform it into a one-dimensional array.  However, when I run my program I keep getting this long error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Duplicate local variable raw_advisor
    Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]
    Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]
    Duplicate local variable advisor_score
    Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to double[]

    at Advisor_Score.main(Advisor_Score.java:16)
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Advisor_Score {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        double l[] = {1};
        double k[] = {2,2};
        double m[] = {3,3,3};
        double All_users[][]={l,k,m};
        double sum[]={0,0,0};
        double [] raw_advisor=new double [3];
        double [] advisor_scored_scaled= new double [3];
        double []advisor_score= new double [3];
        for (int i=0;i<All_users.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<All_users[i].length;j++){
                        sum[i]+=All_users[i][j];
                }
                double raw_advisor[i]=(sum[i]-(3*All_users[i].length))/4;
                double advisor_score_scaled[i]= 2.5*(1-Math.pow(Math.E, -.5*raw_advisor[i]));
                double advisor_score[i] = (2.5 + advisor_score_scaled[i]);
                System.out.println(advisor_score[i]);
                }       
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! Sorry I am new to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify the type when assigning to the values inside the for loop. In Java, variables are defined once with a specific type. That type can't be changed later on in the program, so it does not need to be specified. You also had a typo when defining `advisor_score_scaled`. Try this:

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Advisor_Score {
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        double l[] = {1};
        double k[] = {2,2};
        double m[] = {3,3,3};
        double All_users[][]={l,k,m};
        double sum[]={0,0,0};
        double [] raw_advisor=new double [3];
        double [] advisor_score_scaled= new double [3];
        double []advisor_score= new double [3];
        for (int i=0;i<All_users.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<All_users[i].length;j++){
                        sum[i]+=All_users[i][j];
                }
                raw_advisor[i]=(sum[i]-(3*All_users[i].length))/4;
                advisor_score_scaled[i]= 2.5*(1-Math.pow(Math.E, -.5*raw_advisor[i]));
                advisor_score[i] = (2.5 + advisor_score_scaled[i]);
                System.out.println(advisor_score[i]);
                }       
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs for me. Not sure of course if it gives the answer you want.